# Wrap in an element with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have an `HtmlDocument` that may or may have a proper `<head>` and `<body>` section or might just be an html fragment. Either way, I want to run it through a function that will ensure that it has (more) proper html structure.

I know that I can check if it has a body by seeing if

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
```

is null. If it does not have a body, how would I wrap the contents of doc.DocumentNode in a `<body>` element and assign it back to the `HtmlDocument`?

**Edit:** There seems to be some confusion about what I want to do. In jquery terms:

```
$doc = $(document);
if( !$doc.has('body') ) {
    $doc.wrapInner('body');
}
```

Basically, if there is no body element, put a body element around everything.

Comment: Maybe I am the only one, but I don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: `if there is no body element, put a body element around everything.` even including `html` or `head`?

Comment: @I4V - Let's assume in the context of this question that if there is no body element there is also no html or head element. I can work through the if conditions on my own, it's the actual wrapping I don't know how to do

Comment: @I4V - the real question is how to wrap elements in htmlagilitypack. It doesn't have to be the body element, it could be anything.

Comment: Can you not insert a piece of before/after HTML that explains what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(MyTestHtm);
HtmlNode body = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
if (body == null)
{
    HtmlNode html = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//html");
    // we presume html exists

    body = CloneAsParentNode(html.ChildNodes, "body");
}


static HtmlNode CloneAsParentNode(HtmlNodeCollection nodes, string name)
{
    List<HtmlNode> clones = new List<HtmlNode>(nodes);
    HtmlNode parent = nodes[0].ParentNode;

    // create a new parent with the given name
    HtmlNode newParent = nodes[0].OwnerDocument.CreateElement(name);

    // insert before the first node in the selection
    parent.InsertBefore(newParent, nodes[0]);

    // clone all sub nodes
    foreach (HtmlNode node in clones)
    {
        HtmlNode clone = node.CloneNode(true);
        newParent.AppendChild(clone);
    }

    // remove all sub nodes
    foreach (HtmlNode node in clones)
    {
        parent.RemoveChild(node);
    }
    return newParent;
}
```

Comment: So I'm not sure I understand - would this modify the `HtmlDocument` to now include a `<body>`? I notice that you don't set `doc.DocumentNode`

Comment: Yes, that's what you asked if I understood your question correctly. The DOM is read/write, but not the root, you can't set doc.DocumentNode otherwise than doing a Load(...) or LoadHtml(...).

Comment: Ah, I see, so it sounds like I can still change it with a Load() or I can modify my method to return an HtmlDocument. Thanks.

Comment: Does this mean the solution could or would be different if the node being wrapped wasn't the root node?