# Wrapping an HTML element with another element?

Tags: c#, html

I am writing a program that parses a bit of HTML.  Specifically, I am looking for underlined elements within a list, and turning those underlined elements into hyperlinks.

Here's an example of the pre-converted HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <u>Mode selector </u>
  </li>
  <li>
    <u>LAND ALT</u>
  </li>
  <li>
    <u>FLT ALT</u>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I'm wanting the result to look like:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="triv14522" onclick="TxtLinkAction(15627,15673)">
      <span style="color: rgb(102, 204, 255); font-size: 11pt;">
        <u>Mode selector</u>
      </span>
    </a>
  </l1>
  <li>
    <a id="triv14523" onclick="TxtLinkAction(15627,15674)">
      <span style="color: rgb(102, 204, 255); font-size: 11pt;">
        <u>LAND ALT</u>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
    <a id="triv14887" onclick="TxtLinkAction(15627,15679)">
      <span style="color: rgb(102, 204, 255); font-size: 11pt;">
        <u>FLT ALT</u>
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In my program, I've already built the anchor and span elements for each underlined element.  Just for reference, here's how I've done this:

```
TrivId = trivId;
ActionItemId = actionItemId;
TextLayerId = textLayerId;
var trivIdText = "id=\"triv" + TrivId + "\"";
var onClickText = "onclick=\"TxtLinkAction(" + TextLayerId + "," + ActionItemId + ")\"";
var anchor = "<a " + trivIdText + " " + onClickText + ">";
var span = "<span style=\"color: rgb(102, 204, 255); font-size: 11pt;\">";
```

So, my main problem is I don't exactly know how to "wrap" each underlined element in the list with my anchor and span elements.  If this were XML, I could add my XML element by using `AddBeforeSelf`.  Can I do something similar with HTML?

NOTE: I notice that the C# tag has been removed, and Javascript tag added.  I should clarify:  This is a C# program that is parsing a PowerPoint document.  One of the values that is being brought in is in HTML format.  I am not using Javascript at all, since this isn't an actual webpage.  I'm just grabbing this particular value from the PowerPoint slide, which happens to be in HTML format.

For further clarification, here's the C# method that I'm using.  The resulting, modified HTML will be written out to an XML file.  The resulting HTML will be stored in an XML tag, `<RTF>`, with the valid HTML as that tag's value.

```
public Hyperlink(int textLayerId, int runGroupId)
        {
            TrivId = LectoraTitle.GetId();
            ActionItemId = LectoraTitle.GetId();
            TextLayerId = textLayerId;
            var trivIdText = "id=\"triv" + TrivId + "\"";
            var onClickText = "onclick=\"TxtLinkAction(" + TextLayerId + "," + ActionItemId + ")\"";
            var styleText = "style=\"" + Settings.Default.Style + "\"";

            // build anchor/span and determine where to insert into text.text
            var anchor = "<a " + trivIdText + " " + onClickText + " " + styleText + ">";
            var span = "<span style=\"color: rgb(102, 204, 255); font-size: 11pt;\">";  
            ActionItem = new ActionItem { ActionType = ActionType.rungroup, TargetId = runGroupId };
        }
```

Further explanation:  I'm assuming that I can iterate over my HTML elements with a foreach loop, using something like the below code:

```
    // note: this is pseudocode
    var nodes = htmlSnippet;

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
            // if node is underline element
            // surround node with generated anchor
            // and span elements.
    }
```

I'm just not quite sure how to get my HTML snippet into an enumerable state so that I can iterate over it, and then wrap a particular element with my generated elements.

NEW EDIT:
So, after looking at HtmlAgilityPack, I've incorporated it into my program and am iterating over the Html like so (The variable text contains the HTML value (see first example above)):

```
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(text);
var nodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//u");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
   // insert code here to wrap the 
   // underline element with the generated
   // anchor/span elements
}
```

So, now I'm able to parse the HTML and get only the underline elements.  I now need to figure out how to surround these underline elements with my generated anchor/span elements. I was hoping I could do something like `node.AddParent(anchor)`.

Comment: Do you have a variable referencing <u>Mode selector</u> for example?

Comment: @andrewb Not at the moment.  I was assuming I could loop through the HTML, find each underline element, then wrap that element with the specific anchor and span elements, then move on to the next underline element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to iterate the HTML you may want to use HTML Agility Pack

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Examples here:

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

A decent how-to here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/659019/Scraping-HTML-DOM-elements-using-HtmlAgilityPack-H

You can install it using NuGet.

Comment: Yep, looking at that right now.  Have added the HtmlAgilityPack to my project and am currently attempting to use my pre-converted HTML (which is stored in a variable) instead of trying to load a document, as the examples show.  I already have the HTML value inside the program, so no need to load it as a document.  Once I've figured out how to do that, and am able to iterate through the HTML, I need to figure out how to wrap the underline elements within my generated anchor/span elements.

Comment: I suppose you could iterate through the HTML and push each node out to a new variable but checking if for a UL element, if you find that you can enter your wrapped HTML before or after the current node. Does that make sense?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540415/surround-existing-node-with-another-node-with-agility-pack

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16156217/wrap-in-an-element-with-htmlagilitypack

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the answer, even though I ended up going a different route.  Introducing me to the HtmlAgilityPack was enough to get me going in another direction.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi Kevin, it would be useful for you to post the route you took should other suers stumble across the post.